# Add Class animation onclick using jquery

Tags: jquery, class, animation

I am trying to add an animation class to my div using jquery onclick but it doesn't seem to be working.  Would someone mind taking a few seconds to look at my fiddle and explain to me the reason?  Thank you.  What I am trying to accomplish in general terms is that I want the div to scale up upon clicking the button.

https://jsfiddle.net/dLko979f/

```
<div id="clickable">
<a href=# name="enlarge" onclick="return false;">Click to enlarge</a>
</div>

$(function() {                       //run when the DOM is ready
  $("#clickable > a").onClick(function() {  //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
    $("#clickable").addClass(".popout");      //add the class to the clicked element
  });
});

#clickable {
background: #eee;
color: #fff;
font-size: 2em;
left: 112px;
padding: 40px;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
}
.popout {
    animation: popout 1s ease;
    -webkit-animation: popout 1s ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes popout {
    from{transform:scale(1)}
    to{transform:scale(1.5)}
}
@-webkit-keyframes popout {
    from{transform:scale(1)}
    to{transform:scale(1.5)}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your fiddle.

You where not too far...
But you had a couple syntax errors.
And no jQuery lib in fiddle... ;)

Your code corrected:

```
$(function() {                       //run when the DOM is ready
  $("#clickable a").click(function() {  //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
    $("#clickable").addClass("popout");      //add the class to the clicked element
  });
});
```

Working in this [**Fiddle**](http://%09$(function()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//run%20when%20the%20DOM%20is%20ready%20%09%20%20$(%22#clickable%20a%22).click(function()%20%7B%20%20//use%20a%20class,%20since%20your%20ID%20gets%20mangled%20%09%09$(%22#clickable%22).addClass(%22popout%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20//add%20the%20class%20to%20the%20clicked%20element%20%09%20%20%7D);%20%09%7D);)

Comment: My pleasure! ask anytime! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#clickable a").click(function() { 
$("#clickable").addClass("popout");  
});
```